# Question about script tag in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html

I saw code in a project which looks like this:

```
<script src='http://toolbar.wibiya.com/toolbarLoader.php?toolbarId=22800' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I do not understand what the "src" attribute in a script tag means.
Can you explain it to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the url of a javascript file.

Read [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script)

**`src`**

> This attribute specifies the URI of an
>   external script; this can be used as
>   an alternative to embedding a script
>   directly within a document. script
>   elements with an src attribute
>   specified should not have a script
>   embedded within its tags.

Answer (score 0):

src tag is used for loading .js file in script tag
more info
goto:-
*http:/www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_script.asp*

Answer (score 0):

to load remote js file from specified url